# Integral Calculation or Proof of periodicity

Tags: integration, complex-numbers, periodic-functions

I need help with the calculation of this integral:
$$\vec H(r,a) = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(\psi)\frac{\rho e^{i\psi}-re^{ia}}{(\rho^2+r^2-2\rho r\cos(\psi - a))^{3/2}} d\psi$$

Equivalently I want to know these 2 integrals:
$$ f(r,a)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(\psi)\frac{\rho \cos(\psi)-r\cos(a)}{(\rho^2+r^2-2\rho r\cos(\psi - a))^{3/2}}d\psi$$

and
$$ g(r,a)=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\sin(\psi)\frac{\rho \sin(\psi)-r \sin(a)}{(\rho^2+r^2-2\rho r\cos(\psi - a))^{3/2}}d\psi$$
i.e. $\vec H(r,a) = f(r,a) + i \cdot g(r,a)$

I assume that $\rho = ct$ and $\rho > r > 0$. Also $a \in [0,2\pi)$

Wolfram Alpha could not calculate it. If anyone knows a methodology for this or the answer I would be grateful.

**However**, if anyone can prove that **for $r = ct$**
$$\vec H(r,a) = \vec H(r,a + k*pi) \space, \forall k \in \mathbb{Z}$$
I would be partially ok.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe substitution tangent of half angle can help you. Possibly combine with Hermite root theorem.

Comment: @mathreadler Thanks so you're saying if I expand $\cos(\psi-a)$ I can apply the Weierstrass substitution. Also do you have a link for this theorem. Do you mean Hermite-Biehler theorem?

Comment: Hermite-Biehler is complex analysis. Hermite root theorem is in real analysis https://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermites_rotansats